# What is the difference between mobile & molten rock?

Tags: geology, volcanology, petrology, igneous

In the book [Fundamentals of Geomorphology (Routledge Fundamentals of Physical Geography)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0415567750) by  Richard John Huggett there is a  sentence " Intruded rocks, which must be mobile but not necessarily molten, may have a direct effect on landforms by causing doming of the surface." What is the difference between molten & mobile rock?

Comment: You were far too quick to accept the one answer you received, an answer that completely misses the mark.

Comment: Okay. I didn't about an important point being missed. Apologies. How would you improve this?

Comment: When i read "intruded" i instinctively made the connotation "something warm and ductile" and when coming to "doming" a salt diapir crossed my mind (from foramen magnum to bregma :-)). I'd say the question needs clarification. I would assume that, if it is a good textbook, the riddle may be solved when reading on:-)

Answer (score 2):

Molten rock must be a liquid, mobile rock is any rock capable of moving, sand and mud can be mobile.

Comment: So, sand or mud (mobile rocks) can form intrusions also, right?

Comment: yes, you may want to look up mud volcanoes and sand volcanoes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author's was referring to phenomena like salt diapirs (where mobile salt deposits intrude into heavier overlying sediments).  These produce low hills in the gulf coast region of the United States.  The salt that is moving is not liquid, it is merely mobile.

I do not believe the author of the book you reference was referring to sand and mud diapirs as these deposits are not considered "rocks".